# An otherwise linear matrix equation with the presence of a signum function : reference request

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, linear-programming, matrix-equations

Consider the equation $$\pmb{c}+\text{sign}(G\pmb{c}) = L$$

$\pmb{c}$ is a $n\times1$ matrix.

$G$ is a $n\times n$ matrix which is also positive definite.

matrices $G$ and $c$ are real.

$L$ is a $n\times 1$ matrix whose entries are from the set $\{-1,1\}$.

Can this equation be solved for the matrix $\pmb{c}$?
Suppose there is no signum function there, then the solution is $$\pmb{c} = (G+I_n)^{-1}L$$
and as $G$ is positive definite, there exists a unique solution. But with the presence of the $\text{sign}$ function, the problem doesn't seem to belong to linear algebra. I request for a reference to any subject or book for this type of equations. Does this belong to linear programming?(I don't know anything about it, so I am hoping it is related).

PS: please tag appropriately.

PS 2: $\text{sign}([a_{i,j}]_{m\times n}) = [\text{sign}(a_{i,j})]_{m\times n}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $3^n$ possible choices for the vector $h=\mathop{\rm sign}(Gc)$, since each entry must be in $\{-1,0,1\}$. This gives $3^n$ possible values for $c=L-h$, and one can simply check each such $c$ to see if $\mathop{\rm sign}(Gc)=h$.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372713/an-otherwise-linear-matrix-equation-with-the-presence-of-a-signum-function-ref) for an alternative to brute-force enumeration.